# Understanding an equivalence involving differentials

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

$y^{-1/2}dy=2dx \iff d(2y^{1/2}=d(2x)$

All I can really notice is that: $2x$ is a primitve of $2$ and $2y^{1/2}$ is a primitive of $y^{-1/2}$

Comment: Then you have it. What are you still msissing ?

Comment: What do you want to understand? When they're equivalent? Why they're equivalent? Help us understand what your exact question is.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\frac{d(2y^{1/2})}{dy}=y^{-1/2}$, $\frac{d(2x)}{dx}=2$, so
$$y^{-1/2}dy=d(2y^{1/2})$$
$$2dx=d(2x)$$